# different 'replaces' on same string/line in one command shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Sorry if this sounds dumb, excuse this newbie.
Here is my code

```
line="abcd<>efgh->higk<-1234"
v1=$(echo ${line//<>/;})
echo $v1                   --> outputs "abcd;efgh->hijk<-1234"
v2=$(echo ${v1//->/})  
echo $v2                   --> output "abcd;efghhijk<-1234"
echo ${$v2//<-/}           --> output "abcd;efghhijk1234"
```

without storing the output to intermediate variable may i know how i can achieve this output
**abcd;efghhijk1234**

Thanks for your time

Comment: Bash parameter substitution does not handle nesting or group capturing, so you'll have to resort to piping or a tool like sed.

Comment: Oh I'm not using echo in original code..just used to see the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed` and a pipe `|` to separate the replacement commands:

```
line="abcd<>efgh->highk<-1234"
v1=$(echo ${line} | sed 's|<>|;|g' | sed 's|->||g' | sed 's|<-||g')
echo $v1
```

The above will output the requested `abcd;efghhijk1234`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use multiple `sed` commands, you can combine them all with the `-e` option:

```
v1=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/<>/;/g' -e 's/->\|<-//g');
```

Note: I've changed the delimiter used inside the `sed`-pattern from a `|` to a `/` in the second command.

Comment: wasn't me. you can make this shorter like: `echo ${line//<>/;} | sed 's/->\|<-//g'`

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter Yeah, I wanted to use the `echo` to do the initial replace, but to show `sed`'s usage I had `echo` just output the variable. I could've also skipped it altogether and used `sed ... <<< $line` too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it all in one line with bash parameter expansion, but you can make use of  bash's extended pattern matching to remove both <- and -> at the same time.

```
shopt -s extglob
line="abcd<>efgh->higk<-1234"
v1=${line//<>/;}
v2=${v1//@(->|<-)}
```

Since both items are being replaced with the same replacement text (the empty string), you can match all occurrences of either of them.

Comment: thanks!! my hands are tied no way to accept more than one answer

Comment: The other answer is better, as I originally misread your question as wanting to just eliminate `v2`, not `v1` as well. I'll leave this answer just as a good example of bash's extended patterns, which may come in handy some other time.